# Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a bijective continuous function with $Y$ connected. Is $X$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As in title:
Let  $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a bijective continuous function with  $Y$  connected. Is  $X$  connected?

I know that connectedness is invariant under homeomorphism, but I'm not sure if we need continuity of inverse here. I think that this is true but that if $X$ were connected with the rest of the setup the same, $Y$ would not necessarily be connected. Am I right? Can anybody help me with a proof outline? Thank you.

Comment: Here is a heuristic that I find helpful: if your topological space is nice enough, gluing is continuous, cutting is not, and the two procedures are inverse to each other. To see why this is helpful, consider two applications: (1) a function which glues two disconnected parts together is continuous (this answers your question) and (2) a homeomorphism can neither glue nor cut.

Comment: However, a function that satisfies your (1) is usually not injective. @William

Comment: @Randall my solution essentially glues $(0, 1]$ and $(2, 3)$ together. You're right that such functions aren't usually injective, but it's possible to make it work -- the heuristic is a really good starting point. To do this more generally, you can glue two spaces at a point, then remove one of the points you glued from one of the spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be any set at all, and let $X_0$ be the set $X$ with the discrete topology, and $X_1$ the set $X$ with the indiscrete topology.  Then the function $f: X_0 \to X_1$ by $f(x)=x$ is bijective and continuous, but $X_0$ is disconnected and $X_1$ connected as soon as $|X| \geq 2$.  [$X_1$ is connected with no assumptions on $|X|$.]

Answer (score 4):

Nope! $X$ does not need to be connected. Consider the function $f : (0, 1] \cup (2, 3) \to (0, 1)$ (all endowed with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$) defined  by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{x}{2} & x \in (0, 1]\\ 
\frac{x - 1}{2} & x \in (2, 3)\end{cases}$$

This is continuous by the continuity of $\frac{x}{2}$ and of $\frac{x - 1}{2}$; it's clearly bijective; but the inverse is not continuous, and so the domain can be disconnected.